# Не получается обратиться к закрытому полю через дружественную функцию при перегрузке оператора

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, дружественная-функция

Мне нужно перегрузить оператор `++` как унарную дружественную функцию, заменяющую нулевые элементы матрицы на максимальный элемент. При компиляции выдает ошибку. Как исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
class iMatr {
private:
    int **matrix;
public:
    int i, j;

    iMatr() {
        cout << "i = ";
        cin >> i;
        cout << "j = ";
        cin >> j;
        matrix = new int*[i];
        for (int k = 0; k <  i; k++) {
            matrix[k]=new int[j];
        }
    }
    void input() {
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
            for (int z = 0; z < j; z++){
                cout << "?????? ????????: " << "[" << k << "][" << z << "]: ";
                cin  >> matrix[k][z];
            }
    }
    void output()
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < j; z++)
            {
                cout << matrix[k][z] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    int operator --(int) {
        int m;
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < j; z++) {
                if (matrix[k][z] < 0) m =matrix[k][z] *= -1;
            }
        }
        return m;
    }
    friend void operator ++(iMatr);

};
void operator ++(iMatr mt,int) {
    int max = mt.matrix[0][0];
    for (int k = 0; k < mt.i; k++)
        for (int z = 0; z < mt.j; z++)
        {
            if (max < matrix[k][z]) max = matrix[k][z];
        }
    for (int k = 0; k < mt.i; k++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < mt.j; z++) {
            if (matrix[k][z] == 0)  matrix[k][z] = max;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    iMatr m;
    m.input();
    //m--;
    m++;
    m.output();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Странно перегружать оператор инкремента для замены нулевых элементов на что-то там. Сделайте лучше обычный метод с подходящим именем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, я бы начал с того, что объявил бы дружественным тот же оператор, который реализую...

А то `friend` у вас `operator ++(iMatr);`, а реализуете - `operator ++(iMatr,int)`. Кстати, вам нужен инкремент префиксный или постфиксный?

Кроме того, при передаче по значению ничего у вас работать не будет... Сделайте его `operator ++(iMatr& mt,int)`.

Ну и там, в реализации - раз это не член класса, то к членам надо обращаться с указанием объекта...

И хотя он может возвращать `void`, обычно семантика инкремента иная. Может, подумаете о том, чтоб он возвращал кое-что? :)

Comment: очень корректно и адекватно, а  с последней строкой добавили скромность.  Я просто добавлю :   iMatr  iMatr::operator++(int);